# Reference an associative array from inside a string?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

`"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tables[users]";`

Works but..

`"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tables['users']";`

Does not.

I do not want to do this

```
$usersTable = $tables['users'];
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $usersTable";
```

I heard that it was considered bad practice to reference a key from an associative array without some sort of quotes around it. Is this true or is my first way of doing it preferred?

Comment: If it was that bad it wouldn't work.

Comment: Then is it not considered bad practice? I'd rather use that method as it requires the least markup but I thought there was a reason for not using it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with braces:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$tables['users']}";
```

Or through concatenation:

```
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' . $tables['users'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use curly brackets.

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$tables['users']}";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the folling:

```
$query = sprintf("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s", $tables['users']);

// do some other stuff
```